# Change build time configuration in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, configurationproperties, quarkus-rest-client

I am running a Quarkus Rest Easy based Java application which is pulling data from an external application to load its cache.
However I have recently started getting the exception below and the application cannot seem to be able to load the cache.

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException:
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
RESTEASY003357: GZIP input exceeds max size: 10000000 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[20985]
```

I understand that

**resteasy.gzip.max.input is by default set to 10M**

( as mentioned in https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.20.Final/userguide/html/gzip.html#d4e1407) and this is clear from the error that the size of the decompressed data that I am recieving is higher than that.

Hence, I tried changing the default property in quarkus (https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-resteasy-common_quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input) to a higher value.

```
quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input=2147483647M
```

However looks like this is a build time property and cannot be changed.

P.S :

1. I tried adding an application.properties with custom values but still got the same error.
2. Tried passing the custom value as a command line argument but still could not get it to work.

Seems like I cannot get the value of this property to change.

Can someone point me to how I can change this value at runtime?

Thanks.

[update 1]

There is an existing Quarkus bug for this issue. If anyone else is facing similar issues, please feel free to inform Quarkus team about it here :
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12941

Comment: A build time property can be changed by adding the new value to `application.properties`.  Are you observing that the client is not respecting this value?

Comment: Just to confirm if this is a typo on your question. The property name is `quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input` but you refer to `quarkus.resteasy.gzip_max-input`. The `gzip.max` you have is separated with `_` instead of `.`.

Comment: @geoand RIght. Its not being respected by the client.

Comment: @RobertoCortez It was typo in the question. I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, please open an issue in the Quarkus repo with an example application that exhibits the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that quarkus doesn't recognize the quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input

I have fixed this issue by using  resteasy.gzip.max.input = 33456789

Comment: They seem to have close this bug now ( https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12941). Do you still see this issue with the latest version of Quarkus.

Comment: I didn't test with the last version, but i have this issue with version 2.9.0.